# Laravel 8.x realationship - Use HasMany in HasOne

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I'm trying to use a `HasMany` relation in a `HasOne`.

I have following Models:

```php
class Auction extends Model
{
    //...
    public function bids(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Bid::class, 'auction_id');
    }

    public function approvedBids(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->bids()->approved();
    }

    public function topBids(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->approvedBids()->orderByDesc('price')->take(10);
    }

    public function topBid(): HasOne
    {
        //return $this->topBids()->firstOfMany(); // Not Working
        //return $this->hasOne(Bid:class, 'auction_id)->ofMany('price','max')->approved(); // not working
        //return $this->hasOne(Bid:class, 'auction_id)->approved()->ofMany('price','max'); // not working
        //return $this->hasOne(Bid::class, 'auction_id')->ofMany('price', 'max'); // working but not as I expecting
    }

}
```

---

```php
class Bid extends Model
{
    //...
    public function scopeApproved(Builder $query): Builder
    {
        return $query->where('state', BidState::STATE_APPROVED);
    }
    //...
}
```

---

As you can see in the source, I'm looking for a way to make a relation that retrieve the **Top Bid** (ONE BID) from `topBids()` relation, but I don't know how, and none of my approaches works:

```php
$this->topBids()->firstOfMany(); // Not Working
$this->hasOne(Bid:class, 'auction_id')->ofMany('price','max')->approved(); // not working
$this->hasOne(Bid:class, 'auction_id')->approved()->ofMany('price','max'); // not working
```

Comment: What is the error you get? I'm not entirely familiar with eloquent, But I think your return types on the `approvedBids` should not be a relation like `HasMany` but just `array`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution

```php
public function topBid(): HasOne
{
    return $this->hasOne(Bid::class, 'auction_id')
                ->approved()
                ->orderByDesc('price');
}
```

You see the problem was in `ofMany()` function, which creates a huge `SQL` and I don't know why!

I've returned a `HasOne` object here, which supports all kinds of query manipulations. Basically `HasOne` class, tells the main query, to:

> Retrieve the first record of the query I've provided.

So if we use `orderBy` it only provides an order for `HasOne`'s query. and the main query will take cares of the rest and selects the first record.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately these shouldn't be a relationships

Real question is why are you trying to make these relationships?

Usually you should be using relationships on model to describe how they are correlating together within the database, the rest of the things you should be defining as a scope on a query or a model, or as an attribute.

So, what I'm trying to say is this:

- Keep `bids` as a relationship, as that is actually a relationship to the `Bid` model
- Update `approvedBids` to be a scope (or an attribute)
- Update `topBids` to be a scope (or an attribute)

Then, you will be able to find top bid easily by doing something like this:

- `$this->topBids->first()` -> if it is an attribute
- `$this->topBids()->first()` -> if it is a scope

This is how you can create a scope: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#local-scopes

In the end, you can even create an attribute that will allow you to retrieve `topBid` like this:

```php
public function getTopBidAttribute(){
   $this->bids()->approved()->orderByDesc('offered_token_price')->first();
}
```

Then later you can just do `$this->topBid`.

Comment: Thanks @Ben But could you please take a look at my answer? Cause I was looking for a relation not an attribute or scope

Comment: Why are you insisting for a relation here? It goes against good practices and quite frankly you didn't achieve it  down below either, as that will return the query for you and not relationship. I suggest you go with scope, or an attribute.

Comment: There is a lot of things that is quite based on this relation in my project. I'm aware of scope and attribute, but I can not use them here. And this WILL returns a relation cause the result of `->hasOne` is some sort of query and it works fine and It passed all of my test units! which is not an odd thing. I've found out about this in one of laravel's original classes! and they are using the same. Actually the `HasOne` class informs the eloquent that: "You should select the first record of result of this query" @Ben

Comment: Just look at this and you will understand it, I didn't know that either - 
`\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne::getResults`. Basically `HasOne` relation runs a query and then execute the `->first()` method by default. And the query can be manipulated in our model relation functions!

Comment: One other thing, As you can see, I'm using `... function topBid(): HasOne { ...`, which is a strict return type in PHP. If anything was wrong and `->orderBy()` returned a `Query` instance, instead of `HasOne` instance, then PHP throws an exception!